# where is the scope within a directive div

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Just something I'm trying to figure out at the moment,

If I have a controller, AController, with a variable

```
scope.test = '123';
```

and a directive,

```
.directive('aDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      test: '@aTest'
    }
  }
});
```

with HTML

```
<div ng-controller="AController">
  <div a-directive a-test="abc{{test}}">
    <h4>{{test}}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where is the scope of test within the h4 tags ie nested inside the directive div. I expected it to be the isolate scope and the h4 to contain 'abc123' but instead it seems to be getting the scope from the controller. Is this because the directive test var is specified with the readonly @ tag? I've created a similar example here: http://jsfiddle.net/f46df2gn/

Any thoughts appreciated

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the content of `a-directive` does not know anything about the directive's isolate scope.

If you want to access the isolate scope, you should use a template (via `template` or `templateUrl`).
The isolate scope is also available in the pre- and post-linking functions and the directive controller (if any).

E.g.:

```
.directive('aDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            test: '@aTest'
        },
        template: '<h4>{{test}}</h4>'
    };
});

<div ng-controller="AController">
    <div a-directive a-test="abc{{test}}"></div>
</div>
```

---

See, also, this **[modified demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/f46df2gn/1/)**.

---

<sub>If you want to retain the content of an element (as specified in the view - which will be bound to the parent, non-isolate scope) as well as let the directive add its own content (bound to its isolate scope), you should look into **[`ngTransclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude)** and transclusion in general.

Beware, though, that it's a somewhat advanced subject, so make sure you understand the basics of directives first.

<sub>(In fact, using transclusion it is possible to bind the content defined in the view to the isolate scope, but it's a fairly advanced transclusion usecase.)</sub></sub>

Comment: Yeah sure it makes more sense to use the template. I just thought that anything nested within the div declaring the directive would fall within the scope. Thanks!

Comment: @Cathal: NP :) Take a look at my updated answer for a little more info on transclusion (and the possibilities it offers).